# How to Open the Image in scrollview by clicking on the thumbnail in the order the image are saved in the NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my app i have thumbnail view and i want the user to go to the next view with the imageview and show the particular thumbnail clicked.But this image view is attached to the UIScroll with paging and UIPagecontrol. So i want the specific image to be open and at the specific index so that the user can swipe left or right to see other images. This needs to be exactly like iPhoone's Photo app.

how can I solve this?

my code is,

collectionview.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.gallerycollection indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

        // load the image, to prevent it from being cached we use 'initWithContentsOfFile'
        NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"interior_%d", selectedIndexPath.row];
        NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

        GalleryImageScrollViewController *gallerydetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        gallerydetailViewController.FullScreenImageScroller=image ;
    }
}
```

GalleryImageScrollViewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];
    data=[MyDatabase new];
    slideImages=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name_big FROM interior":@"pic_name_big"];
    [mutablearray addObjectsFromArray:slideImages];
    temparr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    temparr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutablearray];
        [self putImageViewsInScrollView:[temparr count]];
}




-(void) putImageViewsInScrollView:(int)numberOfImageViews
{
   for(int i=0 ;i<= numberOfImageViews; i++)
    {
       // UIImageView *fullScreenImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[temparr objectAtIndex:i]]];
        fullScreenImageView.frame = CGRectMake((WIDTH_OF_IMAGE * i)  , 0, WIDTH_OF_IMAGE, HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE);
        [self.FullScreenImageScroller addSubview:fullScreenImageView];

    }

    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH_OF_SCROLL_PAGE * ([temparr count]), HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,0,WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE) animated:NO];
    self.FullScreenImageScroller.delegate=self;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help

[KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser)

[TTThumbs](https://github.com/doonot/TTThumbsViewController-in-a-TabBar-App)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Three20 library or Apple's UICatalog sample for reference. Below are the links :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

https://github.com/facebook/three20

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it works

1.for thumb nail image give image.tag value when you click on your thumb nail image pass that tag value to next view controller(detailviewControllerObj.index=image.tag) .

2.add all the full screen images (size 320*480) to scrollview in detail page and add that scrollview to view.

3.when you click on the thumb nail image you can pass the index value to detail screen.

4.after that set the scroll view content offset in detail screen.

```
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*index, 0)];
```

when ever you are creating thumb nail images at that time give like

```
for(int i=0;i<[imgarr count];i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    imageView.image=[imgarr objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.tag=i;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

after that in detail view take one integer value as index and synthesize that variable 
when you click on that particular image give like this

detailviewControllerObj.index=image.tag

Answer (score 0):

you can map the index of the image in the array to the "tag" of the thumbnail view when first adding the images to the thumbnail

```
ThumbnailView *thumb = [UIView alloc] init];
thumb.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
thumb.tag = i;
```

and when selecting the thumb view you can fetch the image from the array according to the tag

```
UIImage *image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:thumb.tag];
```

Comment: where should i place this statement UIImage *image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:thumb.tag]; ?

Comment: whenever you want to use the image based on an action on the thumbnail view . from your description i would say when the thumbnail view is tapped and you want to open the image in full screen.

Comment: @ahemd: how can i achieve this using segues ? any  idea ?